# Continuous automorphisms of Q*

Tags: gr.group-theory

What are the continuous automorphisms of Q* = nonzero rationals under multiplication ? or in general F* where F is an algebraic finite extension of Q.They have topology induced as subspaces of C*

I am also interested in finding orbits of F* under action of Aut(F*). I know the answer for  F= complex numbers.

Actually GL_1(F) = F* , I want to generalize to GL_n(F)

Comment: I don't think raising to the nth power should be called an automorphism. It is not bijective on Q*. Maybe you're interested in something different than automorphisms?

Comment: 1) As Yoav Kallus said, your $Phi$ is certainly not an automorphism, as it is not bijective (except for $n=1$ where it is the identity).
2)  Could you say what you mean by an automorphism?  Is it an homeomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}^*$ to itself? 
3) Why do you talk about $GL_n$? It does not seem to be related to your question.

Comment: ya sorry for that nth power is not an automorphism.
But i am interested in automorphism only i.e. bijective homomorphism.
and it should be cts and bijective and inverse also continuous i.e. a homeomorphism from Q* to Q*


Comment: Why is this question closed? It is written "off topic". Is it so easy for all people?

Comment: We have some over-eager question-closers.  Unless they tell us why they closed it, we may never know.  Maybe they saw that the only tag is "group-theory" and closed it on that basis?

Answer (score 3):

I assume by "continuous" you mean in the topology inherited from the usual topology on $\mathbb R$.  A continuous homomorphism will be uniformly continuous (in the natural uniformm structure for a group).  And therefore extend continuously to the complettion, which will be $\mathbb R^\ast$, the nonzero reals under multiplication.  Same for the inverse map, since it is assumed continuous as well.  So we get an extension that is a continuous automorphism of $\mathbb R^\ast$.  Such an automorphism is of the form $x \mapsto x^c$ on $x>0$, where $c$ is a nonzero constant.  (And appropriately for $x<0$.)  But the only maps of this form that map rationals bijectively to rationals are $c=1$ and $c=-1$, I guess.

Comment: Is it obvious that these are the only maps?

Comment: If we talk about completion ,completion of Q* will not be R*, as R* is not complete as 0 is missing(we have a cauchy sequence 1/n which never converges in R*)
You said that that the automorphism phi will be unioformly continuous
but as your argument says that x--> 1/x is a bicontinuous automorphism which is clearly not uniformly continuous (given epsilon and m > epsilon one can easily find 1/n and 1/n+m s.t. [(n+m) - n] = [m] > epsilon ) .
how would one argue that a bicontinuous automorphism will extend to R*?
 

Comment: wrong metric. Use the metric $d(x,y)=|\ln |x|-\ln |y| |+ |sign x - sign y|$.

Comment: Yes, as Will hints, $\mathbb R^\ast$ is complete in the natural uniform structure for the group.  His metric is one that corresponds to this uniform structure.  Instead of $|x-y|<\epsilon$ in the definition of "uniformly continuous" you can use $|xy^{-1}-1|<\epsilon$